# Why the default user can't login into sql server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to run some PowerShell script to install some apps in my pc, the script is trying to create a user and roles for that user in sql server 2012, but I'm getting this error when I installed sql server in mixed mode authentication.

[image]

Getting bellow error when I installed the sql server in only windows authentication mode.

[image]

What can be the issue? Am I missing any settings?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is written clearly:

> cannot open database "Sessions" requested by login

Change it to master and retry